# Access EditText defined in the Main Class from another class in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, class, xamarin, android-edittext

Am engineering a browser application in Android and my WebView happens to be attached to a WebViewClient class, I have an edit text that should display the URL of the current page inside the webview..I can access the EditText in the main class but I can't in the WebViewClient class...I need logic to help me access this EditText from the WebViewClient class, Thank you...Here is the code i have so far

```
 class Internet : AppCompatActivity,Android.Webkit.IDownloadListener, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener
      {
           //Declaring the EdiText
             EditText editText;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle OnSavedInstanceState){
          //Assigning a value to the EditText
         edittext=this.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edittext1);
     }
   //WebViewClient class
public class webViewClient : WebViewClient,IWebResourceRequest
        {
          //Anything that can make me access EditText defined in the main class

        }
}
```

Access view defined in the main class from the WebViewClient class, Thank You.

Comment: having one class directly modify a UI element in a completely different class is not good practice.  It would be better to have `webViewClient` raise an event that the other class can subscribe to, or pass in a delegate to `webViewClient`, etc

Comment: What about defining it in the namespace? will it work there?

Comment: I don't intend to modify but to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by delegate.

First of all, we can declare a delegate type that will be used to control the content of `Edittext`

```
  public delegate void OnLinkSelectedHandler(string url);
```

Create an implementation of `OnLinkSelectedHandler` within Activity contains `edittext` that will set the visited url to the `edittext`.

```
 public void ISVistedSoLink(string url)
{
            editText1.Text = url;
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity.cs` code completely.

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        EditText editText1;
        WebView webView1;

        public delegate void OnLinkSelectedHandler(string url);
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

             editText1= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);

             webView1 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
            webView1.LoadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
            webView1.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView1.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient(this.ISVistedSoLink));
        }

        public void ISVistedSoLink(string url)
        {
            editText1.Text = url;
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Implement the logic to invoke the delegate within the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` method in `MyWebViewClient`:

```
    internal class MyWebviewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private OnLinkSelectedHandler linkSelected;

        public MyWebviewClient(OnLinkSelectedHandler handler)
        {
            linkSelected = handler;
        }
        public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
           
            this.linkSelected(url);
           
            return true;
         
        }
    }
```

Here is running gif.

[image]

Comment: hey now i need to access and modify progressbar using the webcviewclient methods ```OnPageFinished``` and ```OnPageStarted```, how can i use constructors and delegates to do it